# Karaf How to implement changes to a bundle made in features.xml file without reinstalling

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, pax, apache-karaf-feature

In my features.xml file I modified a custom bundle to use a Pax URL Wrap in order to dynamically Import dependencies. I changed the below line:

```
<bundle start-level='78'>mvn:abc.def/aid/1.1</bundle>
```

to

```
<bundle start-level='78'>wrap:mvn:abc.def/aid/1.1\$DynamicImport-Package=*&amp;overwrite=merge;</bundle>
```

I was able to confirm this worked by running the following commands from karaf prompt:

```
karaf@root> uninstall <aid id>
karaf@root> install -s wrap:mvn:abc.def/aid/1.1\$DynamicImport-Package=*&overwrite=merge;
```

Doing that worked but defeated the purpose of modifying my features.xml file. Is there a way to update my currently installed aid bundle without having to restart it?

Things I tried include

1. restarting karaf
2. 

karaf@root> features:refreshurl

karaf@root> osgi:update

karaf@root> osgi:restart

Comment: Depending in the Karaf version used, you may also have access to `features:refresh` command, which re-reads all the feature files AND etc/org.apache.karaf.features.xml overrides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while ... but you might try:

```
features:refreshurl
features:install yourfeature
```

The new features:install you